# Add fading transition to items loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, transition

I'm loading items containing information from some json files corresponding to the category I clicked on.

Below is some simplified code :

```js
var $grid = $('.grid'),
   $cat_link = $('.cat-list a');

// on loading the page for the first time, I define the category to display as the first one
$cat = 'cat-1';

function getCardsList() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'js/' + $cat + '.json',
  dataType: 'json'
 }).done(listSuccess);

 function listSuccess(data) {
    var $card_items = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var card_item = '<div class="col">' + /*stuff from the json file*/ + '</div>';    
   $card_items.push( card_item[0] );
  }

  $grid.append( $card_items ).addClass('is-loaded');
 }
}

// execute immediately the function on the first load
getCardsList();

$cat_link.on( 'click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 $cat = $(this).data('cat');

 getCardsList();
});
```

```css
.col {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  transform: scale(0.85);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}
.is-loaded .col {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cat-list">
 <li><a href="" data-cat="cat-1">Category 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-cat="cat-2">Category 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-cat="cat-3">Category 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="grid"></div>
```

Now I would like to add a transition to the divs that are appended to the grid. I tried hiding the element via CSS and then add a *.is-loaded* class to the grid to fade them in, in the success function, but since they're immediately appended to the grid, the transition doesn't work. Also tried adding a **beforeSend** parameter to the ajax call to hide the items beforehand but with no luck.

If I use a basic **$('.grid .col').show()** or **.fadeIn()** after appending the items, it works, but it's not the animation I want. Cannot use **.animate()** either since it's only animating numeric values.

I tried adding the *.is-loaded* class in the click event after the call to the function but it still doesn't work.

I feel very stupid but just can't figure how to do this, even though it seems so obvious. Thanks for any help.

Edit : here is a [link](http://enora.josse.free.fr/reco/) to the (unfinished) online version. You will totally laugh looking at my script, I'm a self-taught JS noob.

Comment: You want to use the success event callback function: http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: So I tried adding `success: function(){ $grid.addClass('is-loaded'); }` in the ajax call, but it's not working. Is there something else I'm missing ? Could you show me a working example ?

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example of what you need to do. Remove the done() function and include success instead. You will need to place the chained fadeIn() event around here: `$grid.append( $card_items ).addClass('is-loaded').fadeIn("slow");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way to achieve what you want, without having to deal with additional classes are css animations. Example css:

```
.col {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    animation: popIn .2s;
}
@keyframes popIn {
    from {transform: scale(0.85); opacity: 0;}
    to {transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;}
}
```

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

**Another way**, which is a bit hacky, but lets you stick to the classes and transitions:

First, modify you css to look like this:

```
.col {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  transform: scale(0.85);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}
.col.is-loaded {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Then modify your append by adding a delay between appending the element and adding class to it. This is required for the transition to take place.

```
$("<div class='col'>One</div>").appendTo('.container').delay(1).queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).addClass('is-loaded'); 
    next(); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works with animations, totally forgot to go that route. I think it's the simplest way to achieve the effect I need, the method with the delay seems a bit hacky indeed (I had tried to use a delay() previously but was doing it wrong). I'm accepting your answer, but am still interested in knowing why the answer from @Master Yoda is only working on the first load ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of the [ajax success event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) using excellent [JSONPlaceholder API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) for reference.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
getCardsList();

function getCardsList() {
  $.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/1',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(results) //using the success event
    {
      //fade in results (contains bold tags and an extra line break
      $('.container').append("<b>" + results.title + "</b><br/><br/>").fadeIn("slow");
      $('.container').append(results.body).fadeIn("slow");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" hidden="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the example with the fake JSON, it seems to work, but only on the **first** load (the first immediate call of the function). Does it have anything to do with the way I'm calling it the first time ? (I added some details in my post). And why using the 'success' parameter instead of the '.done()' method ? Also I don't get the need to 'fadeIn()' the grid, since it's the items _inside_ it that I want to transition, not the grid itself ? Doesn't seem to work without it though...

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a very easy way to achieve your animation. Just before loading `$.ajax`, add this to your `.grid .col`.

Add this line to your code before the `$.ajax`:

```
$(".grid .col").fadeOut();
```

And then on the loading line of your `$.ajax`, add a `fadeIn()`.

This should work!